# Best way to implement handling of read timeouts of socket connections in asynchronous way using C++ and standard C library

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, select, client-server

There are thousands of clients hitting my server (A) over TCP/IP, I then need to modify the data received and send it across to another server (B), and then get the response and send it back to the client, or handle read timeouts.

Right now a worker thread at server A picks the data from socket send the data to server B over TCP/IP, and in case the server B is slow my server's threads are stuck waiting. Its completely synchronous.

In short I want to implement asynchronous handling of read timeouts or socket read. So the threads can go back to pool after sending data to server B, and in case server B becomes slow server A is still serving requests.
I understand we can achieve using poll, select system calls, but what should be the best way/practice to achieve it. (I cannot use boost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use non-blocking sockets with an event loop library, such as boost::asio, libevent, libuv. Or, reinvent your own wheel.